# Trigger for comparing login name in mysql 5.1

Tags: mysql, validation, triggers, mysql-5.1

Right now it is giving me a 1064 error at the `elseif`. This is my first time creating a trigger in 5.1. I am not sure the version i used before, but I was successful using that one.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS greentrucks.iCustomer;
DELIMITER GO
CREATE TRIGGER greentrucks.iCustomer AFTER INSERT
ON customer 
For each ROW BEGIN 

DECLARE count int;
SET @count = FOUND_ROWS();
If @count = 0
THEN LEAVE

ELSEIF EXISTS ( SELECT *
            FROM INSERTED i
            WHERE  EXISTS (
            SELECT p.email
            FROM greentrucks.customer p
            WHERE i.email = p.email))

THEN BEGIN
    RAISERROR('That Email is already in use!',16,1);
    IF @@Trancount >0
        ROlLBACK TRANSACTION;
END IF
END IF
END
GO
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LEAVE` needs a label. See the [LEAVE documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/leave.html) and the [sample in the LOOP documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/loop.html). Also, you need to terminate your `LEAVE` statement with a semicolon.

MySQL doesn't appear to have any official examples for `LEAVE` within a trigger. [This blog post](http://mysql-0v34c10ck.blogspot.com/2011/06/how-to-disableenable-triggers-on-demand.html) puts the label right before the `BEGIN`. Based on that, try something like this:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS greentrucks.iCustomer;
DELIMITER GO
CREATE TRIGGER greentrucks.iCustomer AFTER INSERT
ON customer 
For each ROW
my_label: BEGIN

DECLARE count int;
SET @count = FOUND_ROWS();
If @count = 0
THEN LEAVE my_label;

... and the rest of your code
```

Comment: With that i get this error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; ... right syntax to use near 'DECLARE

Comment: Hmm, can you try moving it down a couple lines, to right before the `IF`?

Comment: Sorry, the MySQL docs are somewhere between thin and misleading on this. I found [this blog post](http://mysql-0v34c10ck.blogspot.com/2011/06/how-to-disableenable-triggers-on-demand.html) that puts the label before the `BEGIN`. I'll update my answer in a moment to reflect that. Can you give it another try?

Comment: Ok that fixed that, now my only problem is the Trancount, and checking if there is a transaction to Rollback.